# Issues with bind_rows() from dplyr - package loading error?

Tags: r, dplyr, package

I'm trying to use the bind_rows() function from dplyr (ver 0.4.1), but R command line can't find the function. It can find the help for the function, but any efforts to use the function are met with

```
> bind_rows()
Error: could not find function "bind_rows"
```

Am I doing something wrong? I understand bind_rows() was only introduced in ver 0.4.0, but I have a newer version than that.

Here is my sessionInfo()

```
> R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)
> 
> locale:
> [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] utils     datasets  graphics  grDevices stats     methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] lubridate_1.3.3 tidyr_0.2.0     dplyr_0.4.1     swirl_2.2.16    mvoutlier_2.0.5 sgeostat_1.0-25
>
>loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] assertthat_0.1        colorspace_1.2-4      DEoptimR_1.0-1        digest_0.6.4          GGally_0.4.8         
> [6] ggplot2_1.0.0         grid_3.1.1            gtable_0.1.2          httr_0.5              magrittr_1.0.1       
>[11] MASS_7.3-34           memoise_0.2.1         munsell_0.4.2         mvtnorm_1.0-0         parallel_3.1.1       
>[16] pcaPP_1.9-49          pls_2.4-3             plyr_1.8.1            proto_0.3-10          Rcpp_0.11.2          
>[21] RCurl_1.95-4.3        reshape_0.8.5         reshape2_1.4          robCompositions_1.9.0 robustbase_0.91-1    
>[26] rrcov_1.3-4           scales_0.2.4          stats4_3.1.1          stringr_0.6.2         tcltk_3.1.1          
>[31] testthat_0.8.1        tools_3.1.1           yaml_2.1.13
```

Comment: I'd suggest you close all of your R sessions and open just one and re install `dplyr`. It is possible that something messed up if you installed `dplyr` while you had it loaded in another R session.

Comment: Yes, in fact this worked. I took the opportunity to update R to 3.1.2 at the same time. Presumably it was the reinstallation of dplyr that worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing all R sessions and re-installing dplyr worked in this situation. Thanks to David Arenburg for the prompt.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try to call it with the package prefix, e.g.

`dplyr::bind_rows()`

This should work even if there is a conflict with one of the other packages.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that in future.